# Prevent QMainWindow from staying on top on Windows

Tags: python, windows, qt, pyqt

I have a problem with a QMainWindow initialized with another  QMainWindow as parent.

On Debian 8 (PyQt4), it behaves as I want it to: the child QMainWindow can go underneath the other one.

On Windows (PyQt5), however, the child window wants to stay on top.

Here is piece of code to reproduce the issue:

```
from silx.gui import qt

print(qt.PYQT_VERSION_STR)

app = qt.QApplication([])

mw1 = qt.QMainWindow()
mw1.show()
mw1.setWindowTitle("1")

mw2 = qt.QMainWindow(mw1)
mw2.show()
mw2.setWindowTitle("2")

app.exec_()
```

Is there a way to tell a QMainWindow to *not* stay on top of its parent? A flag ?

Comment: If you don't want the second main window stay on top of the first one do not tell that the first main window is its parent. In other words write `mw2 = qt.QMainWindow()`.

Comment: I would still like to have the second window closed when I close the first one. It seems clumsy to have to implement this behavior explicitly.

Comment: The parent-child relationship of `QWidget`s is more than just "closing whan my parent is closing". What is clumsy is to force this relationship between your windows just for this behavior.

Comment: In my real life example, it makes conceptual sense to have the second window a child of the first one: it displays information and processed data from data displayed in the parent window.

Comment: Actually, I cannot imagine a situation where you would like to have the second window closed when the first is closed, without some kind of implicit parent-child relationship.

Comment: @PiRK The fact that the data in the 2nd window depends on data shown in your 1st window doesn't gives any conceptual sense of having them being parent/child. The parent/child relationship for widgets and windows is tightly linked with the way they are drawn and rendered both by Qt and by the window management system, it has nothing to do with whatever data they show. (Also the fact that you cannot image a given situation doesn't mean such a situation doesn't exist.)